SwiftUI icon launch screen not shown properly
For a SwiftUI app I've designed an icon (png-file) for the launch screen and put it into the assets as launchIcon.imageset.
When launching the app in the Xcode-simulator, the icon is shown properly and fits perfectly into the screen.
However when running the app on an iPhone (11, 14pro, iOS 17.4.1) the icon is exceeding the screen and is not fully visible.
The size of the icon is width: 1000 px, height: 1500 px with 1000px/in.
Resizing the icon or changing the resolution didn't solve it.
The settings in the info.plist are as follows:

What do I have to do that the icon fits in its size into the screen?
Thanks for your support
The launch screen looks like this:

However, I want the icon fully visible like this:


Resizing the icon worked for me. Please show an example of an icon, the expected appearance, and the actual appearance.

Unfortunately, resizing and creating x1, x2 and x3 sizes didn't fix my problem yet. I even checked if (a) deleting the setting "Image respects safe area insets" and (b) putting it as first or (c) as last setting parameter in the info.plist didn't fix it

I don't mean the x1, x2, x3 sizes. If your image is 1024x1024, you should make a 100x100 version of it. Put it in the same slot as you would otherwise in the asset catalog.

@Sweeper: thanks for your support. I changed the icon to the size 100x155 px and the resolution to 72 px/in. I imported this file (same size, same resolution) in x1, x2 and x3 in the asset catalogue and unfortunately the result is still the same error.

Having set a background color I assume that the image is your logo. Resize your image to @1x, @2x, and @3x versions when @1x is your regular size. Then update your item in Assets folder.
Note: The background color may also show through any transparency in your image.
Recommended .png with transparency.
